# How to group archive post by year Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post archive I want to group each each custom post by year.
This is my example view for my template. I have already an idea but I want the mos efficient way to create my template.

Heres my template view

```
-----------------
|      2016     |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
-----------------
|      2015     |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
-----------------
|      2014     |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
|    Post Here  |
```

I want to make this as dynamic as I can.
Any suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: as long as your posts are sorted, keep track of the last iterationsn year and don't print the heading if it's the same.

Comment: You can used this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

You can try something like this. Enjoy!

```
 // get years that have posts
     $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'encontros' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );

     foreach ( $years as $year ) {
        // get posts for each year
            $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'encontros' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );
        //get permalinks for each post
            $post_link = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT get_the_permalink() FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'encontros' AND post_status = 'publish' ");

            foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {

              echo '<ul>' . $post->post_title . '</ul>';
            }
              echo '<h2><a href ="'.$posts_this_year.'">' . $year->year . '</a></h2><ul>';
              echo '</ul>';
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't like recommending a plugin, but this plugin does exactly what you need, and it is the easiest way to go.

OK, that out of the way, you should download and install the [Simple Yearly Archive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/#description) plugin. I quote from the plugin page

And also you can find shortcode for this plugin from official website
https://www.schloebe.de/wordpress/simple-yearly-archive-plugin/

Comment: You said "I quote from the plugin page", but you did not add a quoted statement anywhere. It looks like you were about to give evidence from the plugin's page proving that it does exactly what the OP was asking, but then you didn't provide the evidence -- just a link. Adding the "proof" you indicated will make this a better post with more thumbs ups.